# Why does this way of expressing how I want to print an index not work?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

My main issue is with printing the index in the following situations.

```
catNames = []
while True:
    print('Enter the name of cat ' + str(len(catNames)+1) + ' (or enter nothing to stop.):')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break
    catNames = catNames + [name]
print('The cat names are:')
for name in catNames:
    print(str(catNames.index(name)+1) + '. ' + name)
```

In this first scenario, the results are

```
Enter the name of cat 1 (or enter nothing to stop.):
george
Enter the name of cat 2 (or enter nothing to stop.):
sally
Enter the name of cat 3 (or enter nothing to stop.):
chloe
Enter the name of cat 4 (or enter nothing to stop.):

The cat names are:
1. george
2. sally
3. chloe
```

Which is exactly as expected.

However, when I try this for another scenario, it doesn't work. The next example is as below:

```
supplies = ['pens', 'staplers', 'flamethrowers', 'binders']
for i in supplies:
    print('Index ' + str(supplies.index(i)+1) + 'in supplies is: ' + supplies[i])
```

I instead get the error stating "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

I understand there's a better way to express the supplies example using `range(len(supplies)` but I'm just keen to understand why using the `for i in supplies` version doesn't work, although it worked for `catNames`. Thanks!

Comment: just do `'in supplies is: ' + i` . You're **not** doing like the first code, first code was ok, you do different => it fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing well here

```
for name in catNames:
    print(str(catNames.index(name)+1) + '. ' + name)
```

You're doing different here by using `supplies[i]`

```
for i in supplies:
    print('Index ' + str(supplies.index(i)+1) + 'in supplies is: ' + supplies[i])
```

## Solution

do the same as when it worked

```
for i in supplies:
    print('Index ' + str(supplies.index(i)+1) + 'in supplies is: ' + i)
```

## Improve

Use `enumerate` to yields the current index while iterating, you can even choose the starting value

```
for idx, supply in enumerate(supply, 1):
    print('Index ' + idx + 'in supplies is: ' + supply)
```

Answer (score 1):

`"TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".`
the place where it happens: `supplies[i]` 
`supplies` = `['pens', 'staplers', 'flamethrowers', 'binders']`
`i` = `pens` (for example) 
so with this line `supplies[i]` you try to do this`supplies[pens]`

list idx must be like [::-1] or [0] not str, not 'pens'

p.s. the best way to do it is `enumerate`:

```
supplies = ['pens', 'staplers', 'flamethrowers', 'binders']
for idx,i in enumerate(supplies):
    print(f'Index {idx} in supplies is: {i}')

# Index 0 in supplies is: pens
# Index 1 in supplies is: staplers
# Index 2 in supplies is: flamethrowers
# Index 3 in supplies is: binders
```

Answer (score 1):

```
supplies = ['pens', 'staplers', 'flamethrowers', 'binders']
for i in supplies:
    print('Index ' + str(supplies.index(i)+1) + 'in supplies is: ' + supplies[i])
```

The reason why this chunk of code does not work is because `i` in this case is not an integer, but instead the individual string items in the `supplies` list.

So essentially what `supplies[i]` is in this case is `supplies['pens']`, `supplies[staplers]` instead of `supplies[0]`, `supplies[1]` and so on.

You can only use the index to access the specific item in the list using this method.

To rectify this issue, I recommend using `enumerate` like someone else has mentioned.